# flickrj dependencies

Tags: java, flickrj

does anyone know the java packages that flickrj is dependent on? I'm going through the slow and painful compile - jarify - run - locate-library - repeat loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Maven [POM](http://svn.xwiki.org/svnroot/xwiki/platform/core/tags/XWIKI_1_0_BETA_4/core/pom.xml) that references flickrj by name, you may find the listed dependencies useful. Note you'd also have to resolve the referenced project's transitive dependencies.

If you use the Maven [dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) goal you can get all the transitive dependencies downloaded to a directory (you can also use the dependency:sources goal to get their sources)

You can also see the dependencies for flickr-api (a wrapper for flickrj) in its [Maven pom](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/aetrion/flickr/flickrapi/1.1/flickrapi-1.1.pom).